# Using ABAC, how do I express a rule that subject A is allowed to share resource X with subject B?

Tags: design-patterns, xacml, abac

Using ABAC, it is quite easy to express rules like:

```
A Subject (with position = 'Manager') is allowed to perform Action (with name = 'Write') on a Resource (with class = 'Document' and type = 'Report').
```

However, when controlling sharing events, you need to specify two types of Subjects: the person who does the sharing, and the intended recipient.

For example: a Manager might wish to share a report with a Junior in her department.

It is possible to write this as a series of rules involving both types of Subject, but how do you express the "directedness" of sharing, e.g., the Manager can share with the Junior but not vice-versa? I have tried several approaches but they all seem very verbose because of the Subject->Resource->Subject structure and I am not sure that they truly capture all the semantics of access-controlled sharing of content, such as might happen in an online social network.

Perhaps there is an underlying ABAC 'design pattern' for this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could model this in ABAC. I'll be using ALFA as a language in my example. ALFA translates directly into XACML.

### Using additional resource attributes

> Managers can share reports with junior staff in their department.

In pseudo-code, it would become

> A user with role == "manager" can do action == "share" on object of type == "report" if user.department == recipient.department AND recipient.level == "junior"

In this example, the attributes are defined as below:

- role of category access-subject, type string
- action of category action, type string
- type of category resource, type string
- user.department of category access-subject, type string
- recipient.department of category resource, type string
- recipient.level of category resource, type string

### Using the recipient-subject category

Now, of course, you could argue that the recipient is not a resource but rather... a recipient. That's why XACML invented another type of subject category, the recipient-subject (urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject).

As a matter of fact, XACML lets you define your own custom categories in addition to the [standard ones](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-cs-01-en.html#_Ref179369225). As a reminder XACML provides

- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:intermediary-subject
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:codebase
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:requesting-machine

With that in mind, the attributes become:

- role of category access-subject, type string
- action of category action, type string
- type of category resource, type string
- user.department of category access-subject, type string
- recipient.department of category *recipient-subject*, type string
- recipient.level of category *recipient-subject*, type string

And the ALFA policy becomes

```java
/**
 * Control access to reports
 */
policyset report{
    target clause objectType == "report"
    apply firstApplicable
    /**
     * Share reports
     */
    policy shareReport{
        target clause actionId == "share"
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * Managers can share reports if...
         */
        rule managers{
            target clause user.role == "manager" and recipient.level == "junior"
            condition user.department == recipient.department
            permit
        }
    }
}
```

In XACML the policy becomes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--This file was generated by the 
    ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). --><!--Any modification to this file will 
    be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file -->
<xacml3:PolicySet
    PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:policy-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    PolicySetId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axio.report"
    Version="1.0"
    xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <xacml3:Description>Control access to reports</xacml3:Description>
    <xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
        </xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:AnyOf>
            <xacml3:AllOf>
                <xacml3:Match
                    MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">report</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                        AttributeId="com.axiomatics.objectType"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        MustBePresent="false" />
                </xacml3:Match>
            </xacml3:AllOf>
        </xacml3:AnyOf>
    </xacml3:Target>
    <xacml3:Policy
        PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axio.report.shareReport"
        RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
        Version="1.0">
        <xacml3:Description>Share reports</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
            <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
            </xacml3:XPathVersion>
        </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:Target>
            <xacml3:AnyOf>
                <xacml3:AllOf>
                    <xacml3:Match
                        MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">share</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                            AttributeId="com.axiomatics.actionId"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                            MustBePresent="false" />
                    </xacml3:Match>
                </xacml3:AllOf>
            </xacml3:AnyOf>
        </xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="com.axio.report.shareReport.managers">
            <xacml3:Description>Managers can share reports if...
            </xacml3:Description>
            <xacml3:Target>
                <xacml3:AnyOf>
                    <xacml3:AllOf>
                        <xacml3:Match
                            MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">manager</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                                AttributeId="com.axiomatics.user.role"
                                Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                MustBePresent="false" />
                        </xacml3:Match>
                        <xacml3:Match
                            MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">junior</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                                AttributeId="com.axiomatics.recipient.level"
                                Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject"
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                MustBePresent="false" />
                        </xacml3:Match>
                    </xacml3:AllOf>
                </xacml3:AnyOf>
            </xacml3:Target>
            <xacml3:Condition>
                <xacml3:Apply
                    FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of-any">
                    <xacml3:Function
                        FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal" />
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                        AttributeId="com.axiomatics.user.department"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        MustBePresent="false" />
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                        AttributeId="com.axiomatics.recipient.department"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        MustBePresent="false" />
                </xacml3:Apply>
            </xacml3:Condition>
        </xacml3:Rule>
    </xacml3:Policy>
</xacml3:PolicySet>
```

Comment: Great answer, @david-brossard !

Comment: The key to your answer is the use of those custom categories, with a concept of 'recipient', so you can label the subjects by role in the "transaction" . In my attempts, I tried to achieve this with additional `AllOf` clauses and had to split the action 'share' into 'share-give' and 'share-receive', which was very ugly (complex) and verbose. Your formulation is _much_ cleaner. Expressing it in ALFA form makes the intention even more clear. Thank you!